# How to set attribute from code and also insert text inside tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have this code:

```
  span class==I18n.locale == locale_used ? "inactive" : nil
    = link_to(I18n.t('locale_name', locale: locale_used),\
              url_for(locale: locale_used))
```

If I remove the "class" part, everything is fine. Which is the correct way to write this in slim?

Without the class part, the error is: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end`

Comment: If you include the class part what happens? Wrong output, exception, etc?

Comment: Read the update, I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your complex expression inside the `class` attribute.

Slim gets confused on it so you need to wrap it with `()` to parse it correctly:

```
span class==(I18n.locale == locale_used ? "inactive" : nil)
  = link_to(I18n.t('locale_name', locale: locale_used),\
              url_for(locale: locale_used))
```